# How to set a header for csv java logger file.Using logger java.util.logging.Logger

Tags: java, file, csv, logging

I need to set a header for each of the logger files generated via java.util.logging.Logger.
The file format is .csv.
Please let me know if there is any method to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use log4j instead and the way to custom the header like below

Extend PatternLayout and then override getHeader() method. like below

```
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;  
public class CustomePatternLayout extends PatternLayout {  

    @Override  
    public String getHeader() {  
        return "id, event time, message, status"  
    }  

}
```

and then in log4j conf add the following

```
log4j.appender.LOG=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender  
log4j.appender.LOG.File=log/app.log  
log4j.appender.LOG.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd  
log4j.appender.LOG.Append=true 
log4j.appender.LOG.layout=packagepath.CustomePatternLayout 
log4j.appender.LOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
```

Comment: But I need to use the java.util.logging.Logger logging mechanism..now i have implemented so that at the beginning of the file append the header...but the header is not written in the rotation files...any way to know when the file rotation starts or the size of the log files...??

Comment: Hey thanks..overriding the Formatter class method did the trick...:)